# Giving a warning when a specific part of a diff contains whitespace only changes

Tags: git, diff, lint

I'm trying to add a lint rule (ArcanistLinter) that would give a warning when some part of a file has whitespace-only changes (say the editor tried to correct bad formatting from upstream). The problem is that no built-in Linter class has a method that would let me look at the old changes that were there for a file, and I can look at only the modified files. It does, however, provide an API execx that would let me run a shell command such as "git diff", etc. I was wondering if I could use this API to find if a particular line of a particular file had whitespace only change. Even if I could get the original line, and the modified line, of a particular file at a particular line number, I think I could write a function to find if the line had only whitespace changes. Any suggestions?